# how to send pushnotifications to firefox web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, browser, push-notification

I want to send pushnotifications to firefox web browser.......

```
<script>
      function notifyMe() {
            // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
            if (!("Notification" in window)) {
                alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
            }

                // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
            else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                // If it's okay let's create a notification
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");


            }

                // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
            else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                    // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
                    if (permission === "granted") {
                        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
                    }
                });
            }

            // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
            // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
        } Notification.requestPermission().then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }); function spawnNotification(theBody, theIcon, theTitle) {
            var options = {
                body: theBody,
                icon: theIcon
            }
            var n = new Notification(theTitle, options);
        }

    </script>
```

whenever first time my website run  permission popup will come.but when user click allow button how to get browser info like id.I want save that browser id into my database.next time I will send notification  using that id. I did not find any code please help me.please anyone help me.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times (e.g, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074078/how-to-send-notification-to-particular-firefox-web-browser).

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Notifications API](https://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) does not do what think it does.

It can only be used to display notifications from a web page that a user currently has open in their browser. It is comparable to `alert()`, except with a larger variety of formatting options.

It is **not** a push notification service, and cannot be used as one.

Comment: please help me.provide any link.

Comment: please any one help me.